# t if we replace each entry in one column of this matrix by 1’s, then how the determinant will change?

Tags: linear-algebra

In each row of an $4 × 4$ - es matrix the sum of entries is 2008. Show that if we replace each
entry in one column of this matrix by 1’s, then the determinant of the matrix obtained is 1/2008
times the original determinant.

Comment: I mean you could do this brute force by just writing down the matrix $A$

Answer (score 1):

Let $e$ be the vector of ones, then $Ae = 2008 e$, or $e = {1 \over 2008} Ae$.

Let $e_k$ be the vector of zeros with one in the $k$th position and let $A'$ be the updated matrix, and let $i$ be the index of the colume changed to $e$.

Then $A'e_i = e = {1 \over 2008} Ae$ and $A'e_k = A e_k$ for $k \neq i$.

Hence $A' = A B$ where $B=\begin{bmatrix} e_1 & \cdots & e_{i-1} {1 \over 2008} e & e_{i+1} & \cdots & e_n \end{bmatrix}$ and
$\det B = {1 \over 2008}$.

Comment: it is not clear